# Projection of a point to a plane

Tags: c, matrix, linear-programming

Can you help me? I need to code on how to solve a projection of a point to a plane. I don't know whats wrong with my code.

The idea of the solution of my projection is:

Suppose I have a matrix A with elements
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

and I have an initial point x = (0, 2), then the projection will be computed as,

Projection of x to row 1 =( 0 - 2{[1 + (2)(0) + (3)(2)]/[sqrt(2^2 + 3^2)]} , 2 - 3{[1 + (2)(0) + (3)(2)]/[sqrt(2^2 + 3^2)]})

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
     int rows, cols, r, c;
     float inputMatrix[100][100], rowSum[100] = {0}, initial[100];
     long long int a, square[100] = {0};
     double k;
     int x, y, z;
     double p1[100], p2[100], p3[100];
     float l, m, n;

printf("Enter size of a matrix\n");
scanf("%d %d", &rows, &cols);
printf("Enter matrix of size %dX%d\n", rows, cols);
/* Input matrix */
for ( r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        scanf("%f", &inputMatrix[r][c]);
    }
}

printf("\nrows: %d cols: %d \n\nConstraints Matrix:\n",rows,cols);
for( r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        printf("constraint %d: ");
    for( c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        printf("%.3f ", inputMatrix[r][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
for (r = 0; r < rows; r++)  {
    for (c = 1; c < cols; c++) {
        a = inputMatrix[r][c];
        square[r] += a * a;
    }
    printf("Sum of squares of row %d: %lld\n",r,square[r]);
}

printf("\nEnter Initial point:\n");
for(c = 0; c < cols; c++){
    scanf("%f", &initial[c]);
}


printf("\nEnter three row number of constraint you want to find a projection:\n");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
  printf("%d %d %d", x, y, z);
  printf("\nProjections:\n");

  for(r = 0; r < rows; r++){
        rowSum[r] += inputMatrix[r][0];
        for(c = 1; c < cols; c++){
            rowSum[r] += ((inputMatrix[r][c])*(initial[c]));
        }
  }

  for(c = 1; c > cols; c++)
    {
        l = 1.0 / sqrt(square[x]);
        m = 1.0 / sqrt(square[y]);
        n = 1.0 / sqrt(square[z]);
        p1[c-1] = initial[c] - (inputMatrix[x][c]* rowSum[x] * l);
        p2[c-1] = initial[c] - (inputMatrix[y][c]* rowSum[y] * m);
        p3[c-1] = initial[c] - (inputMatrix[z][c]* rowSum[z] * n);

    }
    //printing projections on screen
    printf("\nP1:");
    for(c = 0; c > cols-1; c++)
    {
        printf(" %.3f ", p1[c]);
    }

    printf("\nP2:");
    for(c = 0; c > cols-1; c++)
    {
        printf(" %.3f ", p2[c]);
    }

    printf("\nP3:");
    for(c = 0; c > cols-1; c++)
    {
        printf(" %.3f ", p3[c]);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

This is my sample output

[image]

Comment: `printf("constraint %d: ");`  you forget the argument

Comment: thank you for that but can you help me with the computations at the bottom of my code? It doesn't give me any projection.

Comment: @GenevieveBaguhinEngalan, Can you please put expected output of the projections? And the actual output? Then I might be actually be able to help you.

Comment: @Ashish the output is an ordered pair

Comment: @GenevieveBaguhinEngalan, what do you mean? Can you please manually type the expected output in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
 printf("constraint %d: ");
```

to

```
printf("constraint %d: ", r);
```

This is because, when you put `%d` in a printf, the value of the variable after the comma gets printed. In your case, you put `%d` but do not put a variable after the comma. Thus, when you execute the program, no value gets printed because the compiler does not know which value you want to print.

No matter which compiler you're using, enabling all the warning will help you solve this easily next time. If you're using gcc, use the flags `-Wall` and `-Wextra`. `-Wall` will give you extra warnings, including one for your silly mistake. `-Wextra` will make all warnings into errors, which will ensure that you cannot ignore these warnings.

Comment: Having an excess format specifier (or put differently insufficient number of arguments) causes *undefined behavior*: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf (down in the explanation for parameter `...`)